# Express JS not sending JSON in response to post request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm writing a little AngularJS app that's communicating with an ExpressJS backend for JSON. My server.js file looks like:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

//Express 4
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));

app.get('/questions', function(req, res) {
    res.json(questions);
});

app.post('/new_question', function(req, res){
    res.json(req.body);
    //questions.unshift(req.body);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

When I: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{text: "text", votes: 0 }' localhost:8080/new_question` I get nothing back. What am I missing here? I feel like it must be something exceptionally dumb.

Comment: You need the `body-parser` middleware. If you generate a Express project using the `express` CLI generator it gets added for you.

Comment: Can you write an answer showing how I would do this? I looked at the docs, and I actually tried this before posting this question. I obviously messed something up when I did this. This is my first node/express app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **POST** will need a bodyparser middleware as pointed out in comments.

However, I don't see what's wrong in your **GET**. Maybe *questions* is no valid json? try simply

```
res.send(questions,200);
```

And see what happen.

Also, use a logger to get more infos about your problem : which request status do you get? etc...

```
app.use(express.logger());
```

place it after your *static* call if you don't wanna log static content requests.